# Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if it has decimal places) (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places) but a little different.

I'd like to **round** at most **2 decimal places**, but **only if it has decimal places**.

Input:

```
10
1.7777777
9.1
```

Output:

```
10
1.78
9.10
```

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: the output is a string, i suppose?

Comment: Have you tried using the modulus operator? Or anything for that matter? (See [mcve])

Comment: Seriously? `myNum % 1 ? parseFloat(myNum).toFixed(2) : myNum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select if you need the places or not.

```js
function round(v) {
    return v.toFixed(v % 1 && 2);
}

console.log([10, 1.7777777, 9.1].map(round));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var numbers = [10,1.7777777,9.1]
for ( var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
if ( (String(numbers[i])).match(/\./g) === null ) { // Check for decimal place using regex
console.log(numbers[i])
} else {
console.log(numbers[i].toFixed(2)); 
}}
```

**OR**

```js
var numbers = [10,1.7777777,9.1]
for ( var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
console.log(numbers[i] % 1 ? parseFloat(numbers[i]).toFixed(2) : numbers[i]); } // If number is whole
```